# Let scrollable Div Box take remaining height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm tryining to implement a layout with a header and two div boxes with maximum height.

[image]

The Header is full width and has a fixed height.
The right box should take the remaining height and should'n be scroll-able.
The left box contains a headline and a list with a variable length. The box should also be the maximum height of the window. If the list is longer than the box, a scrollbar should appear.

I tried to add overflow: hidden to the left box and overflow-y: scroll to the inner list, but its not working.
Someone have a hint for me?

Comment: can you please add some working code.

Comment: try giving "height" specifically to that box, then the scrollable property "overflow-y": "scroll" should work.

Answer (score 1):

```css
        body {
            margin: 2vh
        }
        
        header {
            position:relative;
            background-color: aquamarine;
            padding: 5vh;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        #scrollable, #fixed {
            margin: 2vh 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 82vh;
            width: 50%;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        #list {
            /* Reset */
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            
            /* Style */
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: calc(100% - 10vh - 1px);
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding: 25px;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        #list li{
            padding: 10px 20px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>    
    
  </head>

  <body>
      <header></header>

      <main>
          <div id="scrollable">
              <header></header>
              <ul id="list">
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
              </ul>
          </div>

          <div id="fixed">

          </div>
      </main>
  </body>
</html>
```